# iOS device UDID

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, udid

I need to add an iOS device to iTunes connect for develop and testing - the registration of a new device requires a UUID.

Where can I find an iOS device UUID/id?

Comment: It's very simple. Go to Xcode Window and select Devices or you can find it in Organizer.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood/organizerudid

Answer (score 76):

As of macOS Catalina (macOS 10.15), iTunes isn't available. But you can get the UDID using Finder. Connect your iOS device to your computer and open Finder. You should see your iOS device listed under Locations on the left side of the Finder window. Select your iOS device. Details about your device will appear on the right side of the Finder window. At the top will be an icon of your device showing your device's name (such as "Bob's iPhone 11"). Under that will be type of device, disk size and available space, and your battery level. Tapping on the line with the batter level a few times will cycle through other details about the iOS device. One of these will include the UDID. Once displayed you can right-click on the UDID and select Copy to copy the serial number and UDID to the pasteboard.

---

For those with Xcode, you can get the device's UDID from the Devices and Simulators window. Select the Devices tab on that window. Select the iOS device on the left side under Connected. In the detail pane on the right you will see Identifier: followed by the UDID. Right-click on the UDID to copy it to the pasteboard or share it in some desired fashion.

---

Old answer for those still using iTunes

Connect your iPhone to your computer and open iTunes. Select your device in iTunes so you can see the serial number. Click on the serial number. The UDID will take its place. You can copy & paste the UDID that's displayed on the screen.

Comment: And to avoid typing out the UDID by hand, go to the 'Edit' menu, and select 'Copy UDID'. As per here: http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

Comment: Or use my solution here www.my-mo.co.uk/device/deviceinfo.php and email the UDID whoever you choose to.

Comment: You can get your UDID just by visiting this link "http://get.udid.io/" in safari browser of your iPhone/iPad and you will get your Device UDID, now you can use it for any purposes you need, like in apple's Provisioning Profile etc

Comment: @LeonhardPrintz It still works as of iTunes 12.7.5.9. What version are you using?

Answer (score 19):

If one of these tutorials don't do it for you, then nothing will!

http://whatsmyudid.com // For old iTunes versions

or use this - http://get.udid.io // For new iTunes versions

or use this - **Working** https://udidiphone.com for UDID, IMEI, Serial Number, OS Version, Build Number

Comment: Someday science will give developers a way to communicate with the rest of the world. *wipes single tear*

Comment: I do not trust that udid.io service. They are asking you to accept a certificate on your device. To me that is opening you up to a world of risk. Apple removed the ability for apps to access the UDID because it was used to track user behavior. There is a right way to get the info and it is iTunes. End of story.

Comment: @RichardBronosky Either way, TestFlight removed the issue all together.

Comment: Did not work at all, despite sharing my trusted devices credentials with some unknown provider. I recommend rmaddy's answer.

Comment: @StephanKristyn Which method isn't working any longer? Old or new?

Answer (score 9):

If nothing is showing up in iTunes, you have to open up Xcode, go to the devices list (Window -> Devices and Simulators) and then click on the devices tab. Under devices, select your device in the left sidebar and it will show your udid in the main window. You can also just click use for development and it will register your device for you.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I can't open Xcode, or can I? I run Windows 7.

Comment: @user2520946 If you don't have a Mac then use iTunes as described in my answer.

Comment: So the problem is that if you are not an apple developer, you cannot use the iOS7 preview. You must register the device with your apple developer program, so if itunes does not show you because it is in restore mode, I am not really sure how to help. Even if you do find the UDID, you need to register it with your developer account, which I am assuming you dont have if you do not have a mac/xcode

Comment: #user2520946 Actually, just found this, hope it works!

Comment: You should be able to get the UDID by clicking the Apple Menu, and then "About This Mac". Then click "More Info". When System Profile opens, click "USB" and then click on "iPhone". Down below, you should see some info about the iPhone. The Serial Number is the UDID.

Comment: I don't have a Apple Menu, because I have Windows, so what exactly do I have to do on Windows, that's similar to the action you described. I obviously can't click "About this Mac", because I'm on Windows.

Comment: @user2520946 What's the point of all of this? You need a Mac to run Xcode 5. You need Xcode 5 to develop with iOS 7. And ignoring all of that, I have told you how to find the UDID in iTunes.

Comment: @rmaddy This is what I see in iTunes: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6o0G1ThMDKmbHNvXzN0LTZnamc/edit?usp=sharing. So I can not see the serial number. I want to have my UDID. So I can register for cheap on iosbetas.com, where my UDID is needed.

Comment: But I searched a little more on the internet en I found this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aJCG-wKcLE. Now I finally found it.

Comment: @rmaddy, he isnt a developer, he just wants to get a copy of iOS7 on his phone...not quite allowed is it...

Comment: I know you are not going to care anyway, but paying $8 for an illegal pre-release version of iOS seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: There are a few ways to get UDID.
1. Using the website on your mobile safari and click on button to get without iTunes: http://udid.store/  
2. The second that you should plug your iPhone to the Mac laptop and find the UDID on the iTunes. See the guide at the link: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-find-out-your-iphone-or-ipad-udid-3530239/